# How to scale correctly the size of a program for different resolution?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

i'm having trouble doing this, i made a calculator in a 1366x768 computer and you can see the output in the first photo all is placed and sized correctly, but when i run it in a 1920x1080 computer as you can see in the second photo the scrollbars are gone, and some buttons are cutted down in the program, there is no empty space in the right but in the original was here, ecc... all it's not resized for a different resolution. So i found this "win.tk.call('tk', 'scaling', 1.32)" and "1.32" is a variable value, i notice that changing that value changes all the size of the program. How to implement a "formula" that calculate the correct value for the resolution that i'm running the program? In this way i can make sure that my program is resized perfectly for all the resolutions.

[image]

[image]

If you need here is the full program it's long, obviously i cutted the images because they are saved in my pc:

```
from tkinter import *

from ctypes import windll
numeroo,risultato = '',''
def entra_pulsante_uguale(event):
    event.widget['background'] = '#00CB03'
def esci_pulsante_uguale(event):
    event.widget['background'] = '#00b318'
def entra_pulsante_operazione(event):
    event.widget['background'] = '#e87400'
def esci_pulsante_operazione(event):
    event.widget['background'] = '#FF9D12'
def entra_pulsante(event):
    event.widget['background'] = '#1c3eff'
def esci_pulsante(event):
    event.widget['background'] = '#008BC7'
def cancella_tutto(*args):
    global numeroo,risultato
    bottonecanc.configure(bg="#1c3eff")
    win.after(150, lambda: bottonecanc.configure(bg="#008BC7"))
    etichetta_calcoli['text'] = ''
    numeroo,risultato= '',''
def premi_bottone(numero):
    global numeroo,risultato
    testo = etichetta_calcoli['text']
    if len(testo) > 42:
        pass
    else:
        if numero == '1':
            bottone1.configure(bg="#1c3eff")
            win.after(150, lambda: bottone1.configure(bg="#008BC7"))
        if numero == '2':
            bottone2.configure(bg="#1c3eff")
            win.after(150, lambda: bottone2.configure(bg="#008BC7"))
        if numero == '3':
            bottone3.configure(bg="#1c3eff")
            win.after(150, lambda: bottone3.configure(bg="#008BC7"))
        if numero == '4':
            bottone4.configure(bg="#1c3eff")
            win.after(150, lambda: bottone4.configure(bg="#008BC7"))
        if numero == '5':
            bottone5.configure(bg="#1c3eff")
            win.after(150, lambda: bottone5.configure(bg="#008BC7"))
        if numero == '6':
            bottone6.configure(bg="#1c3eff")
            win.after(150, lambda: bottone6.configure(bg="#008BC7"))
        if numero == '7':
            bottone7.configure(bg="#1c3eff")
            win.after(150, lambda: bottone7.configure(bg="#008BC7"))
        if numero == '8':
            bottone8.configure(bg="#1c3eff")
            win.after(150, lambda: bottone8.configure(bg="#008BC7"))
        if numero == '9':
            bottone9.configure(bg="#1c3eff")
            win.after(150, lambda: bottone9.configure(bg="#008BC7"))
        if numero == '0':
            bottone0.configure(bg="#1c3eff")
            win.after(150, lambda: bottone0.configure(bg="#008BC7"))
        if numero == ',':
            bottonevirgola.configure(bg="#1c3eff")
            win.after(150, lambda: bottonevirgola.configure(bg="#008BC7"))
        if numero == '+':
            bottonepiu.configure(bg="#e87400")
            win.after(150, lambda: bottonepiu.configure(bg="#FF9D12"))
        if numero == '-':
            bottonemeno.configure(bg="#e87400")
            win.after(150, lambda: bottonemeno.configure(bg="#FF9D12"))
        if numero == 'x':
            bottoneper.configure(bg="#e87400")
            win.after(150, lambda: bottoneper.configure(bg="#FF9D12"))
        if numero == '/':
            bottonediviso.configure(bg="#e87400")
            win.after(150, lambda: bottonediviso.configure(bg="#FF9D12"))
        if numero == '+':
            if risultato != '' and testo.count (' ') == 0:
                numeroo = risultato
            numeroo += ' ' + numero + ' '
            etichetta_calcoli['text'] = numeroo
        elif numero == '-':
            if risultato != '' and testo.count (' ') == 0:
                numeroo = risultato
            numeroo += ' ' + numero + ' '
            etichetta_calcoli['text'] = numeroo
        elif numero == 'x':
            if risultato != '' and testo.count (' ') == 0:
                numeroo = risultato
            numeroo += ' ' + numero + ' '
            etichetta_calcoli['text'] = numeroo
        elif numero == '/':
            if risultato != '' and testo.count (' ') == 0:
                numeroo = risultato
            numeroo += ' ' + numero + ' '
            etichetta_calcoli['text'] = numeroo
        else:
            if risultato != '' and numero != '+' and numero != '-' and numero != 'x' and numero != '/' and testo.count (' ') == 0:
                numeroo = ''
                risultato = ''
            numeroo += numero
            etichetta_calcoli['text'] = numeroo
def elimina_crono(*args):
    bottoneeliminacrono.configure(bg="#1c3eff")
    win.after(150, lambda: bottoneeliminacrono.configure(bg="#008BC7"))
    cronologia.delete(0,END)
def elimina_1(*args):
    global numeroo
    bottoneelimina1.configure(bg="#1c3eff")
    win.after(150, lambda: bottoneelimina1.configure(bg='#008bc7'))
    try:
        global etichetta_calcoli
        testo_calcolo = etichetta_calcoli['text']
        if testo_calcolo[-1] == ' ':
            testo_calcolo = testo_calcolo[:-3]
            numeroo = numeroo[:-3]
        else:
            testo_calcolo = testo_calcolo[:-1]
            numeroo = numeroo[:-1]
        etichetta_calcoli['text'] = testo_calcolo
    except(IndexError):
        pass
def nulla_cosmico(*args):
    return 'break'
def uguale(*args):
    global numeroo,risultato
    bottoneuguale.configure(bg='#00CB03')
    win.after(150, lambda: bottoneuguale.configure(bg='#00bd03'))
    try:
        equazione = etichetta_calcoli['text']
        if equazione.count(','):
            equazione = equazione.replace(',','.')
        if equazione.count('x'):
            equazione = equazione.replace('x','*')
        risultato = str(eval(equazione))
        risultato = float(risultato)
        risultato = round(risultato, 3)
        risultato = str(risultato)
        if risultato[-1] == '0':
            risultato = float(risultato)
            risultato = int(risultato)
            risultato = str(risultato)
        if risultato.count('.'):
            risultato = risultato.replace('.',',')
        if equazione.count('*'):
            equazione = equazione.replace('*','x')
        if equazione.count('.'):
            equazione = equazione.replace('.',',')
        etichetta_calcoli['text'] = risultato
        cronologia.insert(0,equazione + ' = ' + risultato)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        etichetta_calcoli['text'] = 'Errore'
        numeroo = ''
    except SyntaxError:
        etichetta_calcoli['text'] = 'Errore'
        numeroo = ''
    except NameError:
        pass
windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)
win = Tk()
win.resizable(False,False)
win.configure(background='#3c3f41')
win.title('Calcolatrice')
width, height = 650,620
screen_width = win.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = win.winfo_screenheight()
x = (screen_width / 2) - (width / 2)
y = (screen_height / 2) - (height / 2)
win.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, x, y))
win.geometry('650x465')
frame_barra = Frame(win,bg='#3c3f41')
frame_barra.pack(side=TOP,fill=X)
etichetta_calcoli = Label(frame_barra,text='',width=84,height=2,font=('Ink Free',20,'bold'),bg='#00335A',fg='white',relief='ridge',borderwidth=10,highlightcolor='#3c3f41',highlightbackground='#3c3f41',highlightthickness=15)
etichetta_calcoli.pack()
frame_barra_sotto = Frame(win,bg='#3c3f41',height=25)
frame_barra_sotto.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)
frame741 = Frame(win,bg='#3c3f41')
frame741.pack(side=LEFT,fill=Y)
bottone7 = Button(frame741,text='7',font=('Ink Free',19),width=4,command=lambda: premi_bottone('7'),bg='#008BC7',relief='solid',activebackground="#00A1E6")
bottone7.pack(side=TOP,padx=(35,0))
bottone7.bind("<Enter>", entra_pulsante)
bottone7.bind("<Leave>", esci_pulsante)
win.bind('7',lambda _: premi_bottone('7'))
bottone4 = Button(frame741,text='4',font=('Ink Free',19),width=4,command=lambda: premi_bottone('4'),bg='#008BC7',relief='solid',activebackground="#00A1E6")
bottone4.pack(side=TOP,padx=(35,0),pady=(10,0))
bottone4.bind("<Enter>", entra_pulsante)
bottone4.bind("<Leave>", esci_pulsante)
win.bind('4',lambda _: premi_bottone('4'))
bottone1 = Button(frame741,text='1',font=('Ink Free',19),width=4,command=lambda: premi_bottone('1'),bg='#008BC7',relief='solid',activebackground="#00A1E6")
bottone1.pack(side=TOP,padx=(35,0),pady=(10,0))
bottone1.bind("<Enter>", entra_pulsante)
bottone1.bind("<Leave>", esci_pulsante)
win.bind('1',lambda _: premi_bottone('1'))
bottonecanc = Button(frame741,text='Canc',font=('Ink Free',19),width=4,command=cancella_tutto,bg='#008BC7',relief='solid',activebackground="#00A1E6")
bottonecanc.pack(side=TOP,padx=(35,0),pady=(10,0))
bottonecanc.bind("<Enter>", entra_pulsante)
bottonecanc.bind("<Leave>", esci_pulsante)
bottoneelimina1 = Button(frame741, width=4,font=('Ink Free',19),command=elimina_1,bg='#008BC7',relief='solid',activebackground="#00A1E6")
bottoneelimina1.pack(side=TOP,padx=(35,0),pady=(10,0))
bottoneelimina1.bind("<Enter>", entra_pulsante)
bottoneelimina1.bind("<Leave>", esci_pulsante)
win.bind('<Left>',elimina_1)
frame852 = Frame(win,bg='#3c3f41')
frame852.pack(side=LEFT,fill=Y)
bottone8 = Button(frame852,text='8',font=('Ink Free',19),width=4,command=lambda: premi_bottone('8'),bg='#008BC7',relief='solid',activebackground="#00A1E6")
bottone8.pack(side=TOP,padx=(10,0))
bottone8.bind("<Enter>", entra_pulsante)
bottone8.bind("<Leave>", esci_pulsante)
win.bind('8',lambda _: premi_bottone('8'))
bottone5 = Button(frame852,text='5',font=('Ink Free',19),width=4,command=lambda: premi_bottone('5'),bg='#008BC7',relief='solid',activebackground="#00A1E6")
bottone5.pack(side=TOP,padx=(10,0),pady=(10,0))
bottone5.bind("<Enter>", entra_pulsante)
bottone5.bind("<Leave>", esci_pulsante)
win.bind('5',lambda _: premi_bottone('5'))
bottone2 = Button(frame852,text='2',font=('Ink Free',19),width=4,command=lambda: premi_bottone('2'),bg='#008BC7',relief='solid',activebackground="#00A1E6")
bottone2.pack(side=TOP,padx=(10,0),pady=(10,0))
bottone2.bind("<Enter>", entra_pulsante)
bottone2.bind("<Leave>", esci_pulsante)
win.bind('2',lambda _: premi_bottone('2'))
bottone0 = Button(frame852,text='0',font=('Ink Free',19),width=4,command=lambda: premi_bottone('0'),bg='#008BC7',relief='solid',activebackground="#00A1E6")
bottone0.pack(side=TOP,padx=(10,0),pady=(10,0))
bottone0.bind("<Enter>", entra_pulsante)
bottone0.bind("<Leave>", esci_pulsante)
win.bind('0',lambda _: premi_bottone('0'))
bottoneeliminacrono = Button(frame852,width=4,font=('Ink Free',19),command=elimina_crono,bg='#008BC7',relief='solid',activebackground="#00A1E6")
bottoneeliminacrono.pack(side=TOP,pady=(10,0),padx=(10,0))
bottoneeliminacrono.bind("<Enter>", entra_pulsante)
bottoneeliminacrono.bind("<Leave>", esci_pulsante)
win.bind('<Down>',elimina_crono)
frame963 = Frame(win,bg='#3c3f41')
frame963.pack(side=LEFT,fill=Y)
bottone9 = Button(frame963,text='9',font=('Ink Free',19),width=4,command=lambda: premi_bottone('9'),bg='#008BC7',relief='solid',activebackground="#00A1E6")
bottone9.pack(side=TOP,padx=(10,0))
bottone9.bind("<Enter>", entra_pulsante)
bottone9.bind("<Leave>", esci_pulsante)
win.bind('9',lambda _: premi_bottone('9'))
bottone6 = Button(frame963,text='6',font=('Ink Free',19),width=4,command=lambda: premi_bottone('6'),bg='#008BC7',relief='solid',activebackground="#00A1E6")
bottone6.pack(side=TOP,padx=(10,0),pady=(10,0))
win.bind('6',lambda _: premi_bottone('6'))
bottone6.bind("<Enter>", entra_pulsante)
bottone6.bind("<Leave>", esci_pulsante)
bottone3 = Button(frame963,text='3',font=('Ink Free',19),width=4,command=lambda: premi_bottone('3'),bg='#008BC7',relief='solid',activebackground="#00A1E6")
bottone3.pack(side=TOP,padx=(10,0),pady=(10,0))
bottone3.bind("<Enter>", entra_pulsante)
bottone3.bind("<Leave>", esci_pulsante)
win.bind('3',lambda _: premi_bottone('3'))
bottonevirgola = Button(frame963,text=',',font=('Ink Free',19),width=4,command=lambda: premi_bottone(','),bg='#008BC7',relief='solid',activebackground="#00A1E6")
bottonevirgola.pack(side=TOP,padx=(10,0),pady=(10,0))
bottonevirgola.bind("<Enter>", entra_pulsante)
bottonevirgola.bind("<Leave>", esci_pulsante)
win.bind('.',lambda _: premi_bottone(','))
bottonevuoto = Button(frame963,text='',font=('Ink Free',19),width=4,bg='#008BC7',relief='solid',activebackground="#00A1E6")
bottonevuoto.pack(side=TOP,padx=(10,0),pady=(10,0))
bottonevuoto.bind("<Enter>", entra_pulsante)
bottonevuoto.bind("<Leave>", esci_pulsante)
frame_simboli = Frame(win,bg='#3c3f41')
frame_simboli.pack(side=LEFT,fill=Y)
bottonediviso = Button(frame_simboli,text='/',font=('Ink Free',19),width=4,bg='orange',relief='solid',activebackground="#e87400",command=lambda: premi_bottone('/'))
bottonediviso.pack(side=TOP,padx=(10,0))
bottonediviso.bind("<Enter>", entra_pulsante_operazione)
bottonediviso.bind("<Leave>", esci_pulsante_operazione)
win.bind('/',lambda _: premi_bottone('/'))
bottoneper = Button(frame_simboli,text='x',font=('Ink Free',19),width=4,bg='orange',relief='solid',activebackground="#e87400",command=lambda: premi_bottone('x'))
bottoneper.pack(side=TOP,padx=(10,0),pady=(10,0))
bottoneper.bind("<Enter>", entra_pulsante_operazione)
bottoneper.bind("<Leave>", esci_pulsante_operazione)
win.bind('*',lambda _: premi_bottone('x'))
bottonemeno = Button(frame_simboli,text='-',font=('Ink Free',19),width=4,bg='orange',relief='solid',activebackground="#e87400",command=lambda: premi_bottone('-'))
bottonemeno.pack(side=TOP,padx=(10,0),pady=(10,0))
bottonemeno.bind("<Enter>", entra_pulsante_operazione)
bottonemeno.bind("<Leave>", esci_pulsante_operazione)
win.bind('-',lambda _: premi_bottone('-'))
bottonepiu = Button(frame_simboli,text='+',font=('Ink Free',19),width=4,bg='orange',relief='solid',activebackground="#e87400",command=lambda: premi_bottone('+'))
bottonepiu.pack(side=TOP,padx=(10,0),pady=(10,0))
bottonepiu.bind("<Enter>", entra_pulsante_operazione)
bottonepiu.bind("<Leave>", esci_pulsante_operazione)
win.bind('+',lambda _: premi_bottone('+'))
bottoneuguale = Button(frame_simboli,text='=',font=('Ink Free',19),width=4,bg='#009C00',activebackground="#00CB03",relief='solid',command=uguale)
win.bind('<Return>',uguale)
bottoneuguale.bind("<Enter>", entra_pulsante_uguale)
bottoneuguale.bind("<Leave>", esci_pulsante_uguale)
bottoneuguale.pack(side=TOP,padx=(10,0),pady=(10,0))
framecronologia = Frame(win,bg='#3c3f41')
framecronologia.pack(side=LEFT,fill=Y)
cronologia = Listbox(framecronologia,width=13,height=9,bg='#005E44',relief='ridge',borderwidth=11,font=('Courier',20),fg='white')
cronologia.pack(padx=(35,0))
scrollbar2 = Scrollbar(framecronologia, orient="horizontal")
scrollbar2.pack(fill=X,padx=(35,0))
scrollbar2.config(command=cronologia.xview)
cronologia.config(xscrollcommand=scrollbar2.set)
frame_barra_verticale = Frame(win)
frame_barra_verticale.pack(side=LEFT,fill=Y)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame_barra_verticale)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
scrollbar.config(command=cronologia.yview)
cronologia.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
cronologia.bind("<Button-1>", nulla_cosmico)
cronologia.bind("<Motion>", nulla_cosmico)
cronologia.bind("<Leave>", nulla_cosmico)
win.bind('<BackSpace>',cancella_tutto)
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: What if you do nothing but remove the call to `win.geometry`? My guess is that you're simply forcing the window to be smaller than it needs to be. Tkinter is very good at calculating the optimal size of windows based on what is inside the window. I also recommend letting the user resize the window. This will allow you to resize it during development to see if the internal widgets behave properly when resized. If you can make it resize properly, then it will resize automatically when run on different resolutions.

Comment: Hi Bryan, i tried what you said but it's still not my goal, i read a lot of your commets and i know you are good please help me with this i really can't find a solution, basically i need to calculate a precise value of x -> win.tk.call('tk', 'scaling', x), i tried calculating "dpi = win.winfo_fpixels('1i')" and then "x = dpi / 72" but the value it's not correct for a resize, if i put 1.3 manually it works but my formula's output is 1.6... How to solve?